# many to many with order

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<X>()
.HasMany(u => u.Ys)
.WithMany()
.Map(m =>
{
    m.ToTable("XToYs");
    m.MapLeftKey("XId");
    m.MapRightKey("YId");
});
```

to model a many to many relationship between X and Y. Is there a way to add an order to this like this:

```
XId Yid Order
1   2   1
1   3   2
```

Comment: by order do you mean like an `Order By` or do you mean some extra data (i.e., `payload` in the many-to-many table)?

Comment: sorry I just noticed that I did not format the stuff nicely. I have tried to capture this in the table at the end. Here entity X with Id 1 has 2 entities Y, where Y with Id 2 comes before Y with the Id 3. I guess this is what you describe as payload.

Comment: In that case there is no option except dividing the many to many relationship in two one to many relationship and and insert new poco class with your desired property Order inside it.

Comment: fair enough - good old nhibernate used to do that (-:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you want to do is this:

```
public class XY
{
    public int XId {get; set;}
    public virtual X X{get; set;}
    public int YId {get; set;}
    public virtual Y Y {get; set;}
    public int Order {get; set;}
}
```

and in your modelBuilder:

```
builder.Entity<X>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Y)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(k => k.YId);

builder.Entity<Y>()
    .HasMany(y => y.X)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(k => k.XId);
```

Comment: Hi SOfantic - can you please be so kind and clarify why you need int XId and virtual int YId?

Comment: @csetzkorn actually it should only be there for navigation properties, my bad.

Comment: Can you adapt please?